# execute javascript files in succession using node command line

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a couple of scripts to setup a database for a project and the files need to run in succession where each file only run after the previous has finished.

```
// A manual run from bash/terminal would look like this:
node ./db_init.js
node ./db_seed1.js
node ./db_import_data.js
node ./db_seed2.js
```

Each file is "executing itself" like so:

```
// db_init.js
const initTables = async () => {
  await sequelize.sync({force: true})
}

initTables() // <--- self executing
```

Is there any SIMPLE way I can run all 4 files in succession where each file is waiting for the completion of the previous one.

*The crux is that I want to keep the "self-executing" nature of the files where they "call themselves" so that you still could run one of them manually like so `node ./db_init.js`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the node CLI doesn't have any options to do quite what you want. The `-r` flag could get close but it wouldn't sequence the scripts properly. eg `node -r  ./db_init.js -r ./db_seed1.js ...` would run all the scripts in parallel, not in succession.

If you change each script to export the promise for the work they do (eg change the line `initTables()` to `module.exports = initTables()`) then you could make a wrapper `runScripts.js` script like:

```
(async () => {
    for (const script of process.argv.slice(2)) { // slice(2) chops off 'node', 'runScript.js'
        await require(script);
    }
})().catch(e => console.error(e))
```

and then run it like `node ./runScripts.js ./db_init.js ./db_seed1.js ./db_import_data.js ./db_seed2.js`

Comment: Thanks! The combination of `await` and `require` did the trick!